# Mostrar coordenadas en un mapa de google con jquery Asp.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

Hola tengo un proyecto en asp.net mvc el cual trae unas coordenas de la base de datos y debe mostrar los marcadores en un mapa, pero no lo hace.
Aqui dejo el codigo y el resultado en la consola del navegador.

```html
@model Models.VerRutaModel

<style type="text/css">
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close fa fa-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="VerRutaModal">Ruta </h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="height: 400px;">
<div id="map"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer text-right">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Aceptar</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
var locations = [],
center = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 20);

function initialize() {
@foreach (RutaRastreo ruta in Model.RutaRastreo)
{
if (ruta.Gps_Latitud != 0 && ruta.Gps_Longitud != 0)
{
@:locations.push([@ruta.Gps_Latitud, @ruta.Gps_Longitud]);
}
}  
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 10,
center: center,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker,
    i,
    position,
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: position,
map: map
});

bounds.extend(position); // añado la posición a bounds
console.log(position);

google.maps.event.addListener(
     marker,
    "click",
    (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    };
  })(marker, i)
 );
}
map.fitBounds(bounds); 
}
   initialize();
</script>

}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
Use estos dos metodos para eliminar las "," en las coordendas, pero el resultado fue el mismo

locations = locations.map((elemento) => {
    return [
       elemento[0], 
       Number(elemento[1] + '.' + elemento[2]), 
       Number(elemento[3] + '.' + elemento[4])
    ];
});
O bien, en ES5

locations = locations.map(function(elemento) {
    return [
       elemento[0], 
       Number(elemento[1] + '.' + elemento[2]), 
       Number(elemento[3] + '.' + elemento[4])
    ];
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba reemplazar `center: center,` con `center: {lat: -35.999792, lng:147.463352},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: nunca he usado asp.net-mvc así que no tengo idea de la utilidad de la etiqueta `<text>` pero esta respuesta debiera servir igual.*

---

Empecemos desde el final retrocediento hasta el principio.

**Primero:**

Cuando declaras tus markers, quieres asociar a cada uno un listener que al pinchar sobre el marker abra el infowindow con un contenido `locations[i][0]`. Esto me hace pensar que en realidad tus locations **no son** `google.maps.LatLng` ni `google.maps.LatLngLiteral` **sino arrays** compuestos por

```
[ruta.comentario, ruta.Gps_Latitud, ruta.Gps_Longitud]
```

En ese caso, `locations` es un arrar de arrays y el centro del mapa debiese ser declarado en forma independiente. Por ejemplo usando un [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral):

```
var locations=[],
    center = { lat: 10, lng: 20};
```

O bien un [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng)

```
var locations=[],
    center = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 20);
```

Porque el centro de un mapa puede ser tanto un `LatLng` como un `LatLngLiteral` (ver [documentación de MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.center))

**Segundo**, en cada iteración **redefines** `locations` como un array que contiene un objeto [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng)

```
locations = [new google.maps.LatLng(@ruta.Gps_Latitud, @ruta.Gps_Longitud)];
```

Al final del bucle, `locations` sólo contendrá el último objeto `google.maps.LatLng`.

En realidad lo que tú quieres es tener un array de arrays con la forma

```
[
    [ruta.comentario, ruta.Gps_Latitud, ruta.Gps_Longitud],
    [ruta.comentario, ruta.Gps_Latitud, ruta.Gps_Longitud],
    [ruta.comentario, ruta.Gps_Latitud, ruta.Gps_Longitud]
]
```

Por lo cual en vez de redeclarar tienes que ir añadiendo elementos a `locations` :

```
 var locations = [];

@foreach (TablaRuta ruta in Model.Ruta)  {
  if (ruta.Gps_Latitud != 0 && ruta.Gps_Longitud != 0)     {
     locations.push([@ruta.comentario, @ruta.Gps_Latitud, @ruta.Gps_Longitud]);
  }
}
```

Después de lo cual sí tendrás un array de arrays.

Con esas modificaciones, el resto del código debiera funcionar. Hay, eso sí, una mala práctica en medio, y es que tu función `initialize` tiene un parámetro `locations` que hace `shadowing` de la variable global. Como buena práctica, debieras ponerle otro nombre al parámetro para distinguir si hablamos de la variable global o del parámetro, o bien omitir por completo el parámetro, porque la función ya tiene acceso a `locations` en el ámbito global.

## Bonus Track

Supongamos que no conoces de antemano el centro del mapa, y quieres deducirlo a partir de los markers que se vayan a dibujar. En ese caso, puedes crear un elemento [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds) e irlo expandiendo con cada marker añadido, para luego decirle al mapa que adopte una posición y zoom que contenga los markers, usando el método [fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds):

```
var marker, 
      i, 
      position, 
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
    });

    bounds.extend(position); // añado la posición a bounds

    google.maps.event.addListener(
      marker,
      "click",
      (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
      })(marker, i)
    );
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

O bien si quieres mantener el zoom del mapa y sólo modificar su centro en base a los markers:

```
 map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

## Edit

Ya que al parecer las coordenadas vienen del backend usando coma como separador decimal, significa que se está declarando `locations`  como si fuera, por ejemplo:

```
var locations = [
    ['casa', 3,33654, 2,35454],
    ['trabajo', 4,54825, 8,47574]
];
```

Javascript interpreta la coma como separador entre elementos de un array, por lo cual se forman arrays de 5 elementos, como si declarases:

```
var locations = [
    ['casa', 3, 33654, 2, 35454],
    ['trabajo', 4, 54825, 8, 47574]
];
```

Como `.replace` es un método de `string`, en javascript, probablemente dentro de un bucle de asp.net no pueda aplicarse. En ese caso, la solución sería que después de llenar el array:

```
@foreach (TablaRuta ruta in Model.Ruta)  {
  if (ruta.Gps_Latitud != 0 && ruta.Gps_Longitud != 0)     {
     locations.push([@ruta.comentario, @ruta.Gps_Latitud, @ruta.Gps_Longitud]);
  }
}
```

Se refiniera `locations` usando el método `.map` que tienen los arrays, en la forma:

```
locations = locations.map((elemento) => {
    return [
       elemento[0], 
       Number(elemento[1] + '.' + elemento[2]), 
       Number(elemento[3] + '.' + elemento[4])
    ];
});
```

O bien, en ES5

```
locations = locations.map(function(elemento) {
    return [
       elemento[0], 
       Number(elemento[1] + '.' + elemento[2]), 
       Number(elemento[3] + '.' + elemento[4])
    ];
});
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por su respuesta, he modificado mi codigo, pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: uh, por lo que veo en tu captura de pantalla las coordenadas vienen con una coma como separador decimal. Debiera ser un punto.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, como podria solucionar eso? :C

Comment: `locations.push([@ruta.description, @ruta.Gps_Latitud.replace(',' , '.'), @ruta.Gps_Longitud.replace(',' , '.')])`

Comment: Hola, ya lo probe pero no me funciona, Uncaught TypeError: locations.push(...).replace is not a function

Comment: tienes que aplicar el replace a los parámetros, lo estás aplicando afuera del push

Comment: ya lo intente solo a los parametros y me marca error

Comment: Estoy en lo cierto en mi suposición que tu array es [descripcion, latitud, longitud] ? Pregunto porque llenas el infowindow con el elemento [0] y este debiera ser un nombre o algo parecido

Comment: Dejé una sugerencia en la respuesta, veamos si te sirve

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, probe con las dos opciones y me muestra los valores asi :  [10, NaN, NaN]

Comment: puedes hacer un console.log de `locations[0]` después del bucle?

Comment: me da esto como resultado [10, 68720245361, -150, 788024291992]
0: 10
1: 68720245361
2: -150
3: 798024291992
length: 4

Comment: Bueno, entonces usa mi ejemplo partiendo del elemento 0 hasta el 3. Yo todo este tiempo he supuesto que el elemento 0 era un nombre. Si tu array debe contener dos coordenadas entonces también debes generar los markers con el elemento 0 y el 1, no con el 1 y el 2. Los arrays comienzan de 0 en javascript.

Comment: hola, ya lo he modificado partiendo del elemento 0 y el el resultado es el mismo

Comment: No se me ocurre nada más :(

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudo bastante, seguiré buscando